# jQuery - Fire 'mouseleave' event when mouse is not over two objects

Tags: jquery, events, mouseleave

How do I fire the jQuery's

```
mouseleave
```

event when the mouse is NOT over elementA AND  elementB ?

For a better understanding see example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dp3C5/).

Wrapping both of the elements in a containerC and fire the event from that is not an option,
because I have elementA and elementB in two different table cells.

I'm not trying to make a multiple element selection (,). I'm traying to emulate the logical AND (&&). As above, the event must be fired when the mouse is neither over elementA nor elementB...

I hope you understand my question...

Comment: What would cause the event to fire?

Comment: Leaving both of them, not just one.

Comment: updated answer to comply with question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will add a class `mouse_over` when mouse enters either of the elements. It will then check that there are no `mouse_over` elements when a `mouseleave` is detected. The setTimeout is required to allow the mouseenter to fire before the mouseleave and may require additional tweaking to eliminate race conditions

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dp3C5/6/)

```
$('.myDiv, .myDiv1').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass('mouse_over')
})
$('.myDiv, .myDiv1').mouseleave(function () {
    $this = $(this)
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        $this.removeClass('mouse_over')
        if ($('.mouse_over').length == 0) {
            console.log('not_in_either');
        }
    }, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As variant - set class for example "hovered" to div when mouseon, and remove it when mouseleave.

Then create function, that check elementA and elementB don't have "hovered" class, and if both true - do anything. Bind this function to elementA and elementB mouseleave event.

Answer (score 0):

well i have updated your demo it should work on button click you can change according to your requirement.

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/bladebreaker/Dp3C5/3/) is the demo

```
$('.myDiv').mouseleave(function(){ console.log('out'); });
         $('input').click(function(){
              alert('a');
              $('.myDiv').trigger('mouseleave');
         });
```

Comment: You've triggered the event by pressing the button. That's quite easy. What I'm looking for is a way to trigger the event by mouseleaving both of the boxes. Not just one of them...